# Merging 2 cells where cell numbers are variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have to merge 2 cells where the range might vary at every run. I am trying with the below code, but there is some error with the code, which I am not able to identify. For fixed range its working fine, but for variable it is showing error. Line no is the cell number which needs to be merged, and it will vary at every run:

```
Range("D" & line_no & ":" "E" & line_no & ).Select
Range("D" & line_no).Activate
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = True
End With
```

Comment: between ":" and "E" there needs to be an &

Comment: or instead of `":" "E"` write `":E"` and omit the `&` in the end: `Range("D" & line_no & ":E" & line_no).Select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to get rid of the `Select` in general. You could do it like this:

```
With Range("D" & line_no & ":" & "E" & line_no)
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in string concatenation. Comments cover that part.

If this range would be used throughout the program, I'd recommend stroing this range in variable:

define string which will point desired range: `Dim rng As String: rng = "D" & line_no & ":E" & line_no`, then use it like this:

```
Range(rng).Select
Range(rng).Activate
```

OR

define range and store range in the variable instead of a string"

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("D" & line_no & ":E" & line_no)
rng.Select
rng.Activate
'...
```